# Can the page title (browser) be changed

Tags: support, tags, titles

Currently the title of a page (what you see on browser heading or tab label) includes the first tag of the question followed by the actual question.

For example:

- [Do Latter-day Saints believe in an infinite regression of Gods?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99475/22319)
- [Are the ten commandments a reflection of the character of God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99512/22319)
- [Who or what does LDS worship that qualifies them as monotheist?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99459/22319)

All start with `nature of god -`  then the question.

Or these:

- [Question on Zondervan source materials?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99455/22319)
- [What is the earliest canon law reference that contraceptive intercourse does not consummate a marriage?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99451/22319)
- [Saints who chose wrong vocation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/99449/22319)

All start with `catholicisim -`  then the question.

Stackoverflow does not seem to follow this pattern always. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38485607/3462319 does not start with `docker -` , but https://stackoverflow.com/q/34226061/3462319 does start with `migration -` , but that isn't the first tag. Additional examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4192847/3462319 starts with `javascript -`  but https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588/3462319 does not though it also contains only that tag.

I admit I probably have a problem with the number of tabs I have open, but this is sometimes confusing on selecting the correct tab. Is there a reason to include the first tag (any tag) in the page title? How is the tag selected? Is it newer questions that have tag in the title? Is the tag being AI selected?

Comment: I think they start with the tag that has the most questions, maybe you'll get a CM to answer your question better in a few months! The answer might be on meta.stackexchange.com though

Comment: found it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions, basically its for SEO